# Django read cookie in template tag

Tags: python, django

Is it posible to read a cookie in a template tag?

I set the cookie in a middleware but I'd like to read in a template tag.

```
def process_response(self, request, response):
    response.set_cookie('changed', 'yes')
    response.set_cookie('choose', request.LANGUAGE_CODE)
    return response
```

Thanks

Answer (score 7):

Since cookies are key/value pairs, you can read the value of a cookie in a template using the dot notation as shown below.

In your views:

```
def process_response(self, request, response):
response.set_cookie('changed', 'yes')
response.set_cookie('choose', request.LANGUAGE_CODE)
return response
```

And in your template:

```
{{ request.COOKIES.cookie_name }}
```

Comment: Simples :) although probably best to wrap it in an `{% if request.COOKIES.cookie_name %}`.

Comment: @zelanix, just to be safe. I agree

Answer (score 5):

You have to create a template tag with ***takes_context***

```
@register.simple_tag(takes_context = True)
def custom_template_tag_name(context, value1, value2):
    request = context['request']
    result = request.COOKIES.get('cookie_name', '')
    return result
```

Comment: This assumes the cookie exists.  Otherwise use: result = request.COOKIES.get(cookie_name,'')

Answer (score 5):

Marcos' answer should be accepted.

Here's how I used Marcos' answer in my case:

**1 - Django view (in views.py):**

```
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response

def helloWorld(request):
    response = render_to_response("awesomeapp/hello.html", {
            'person_name': "Mark"
        }, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
    person_age = 26
    response.set_cookie('the_new_number', person_age, max_age = 5000000) # 5million secs is almost two months, adjust as appropriate
    return response
```

**2 - In marktags.py:**

```
# To read cookies within django template, from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26301447/django-read-cookie-in-template-tag
@register.simple_tag(takes_context = True)
def cookie(context, cookie_name): # could feed in additional argument to use as default value
    request = context['request']
    result = request.COOKIES.get(cookie_name,'') # I use blank as default value
    return result
```

Note that marktags.py file, where I have all my custom filters, is [stored inside the `templatetags` directory](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/howto/custom-template-tags/)
*(In my case, I use django-allauth so I saved my custom file `marktags.py` beside the `template_tags.py` file in `myapp/allauth/account/templatetags` folder)*

**3 - Finally, hello.html includes the following:**

```
<head>
    {% load marktags %}
</head>

<body>
    {{ person_name }} is {% cookie 'the_new_number' %} years old.
</body>
```

Note the `{%` syntax, not `{{` for accessing the cookie

Here's [another example](http://www.arruda.blog.br/programacao/django-simple-template-tag-without-a-string-as-argument/)

If you're new to cookies, I recommend an extension such as 
[EditThisCookie](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/editthiscookie/fngmhnnpilhplaeedifhccceomclgfbg?hl=en).
You can see only the server understood how the person's name was displayed, but the browser's cookie contains the value of the person's age